# CASE statements for creating a dynamic Excel spreadsheet from my configuration in the DB

Tags: sql, optimization, case

I want to make dynamic representation of the settings of the system from my DataBase. Before I manually edited a Excel spreadsheet with the new configration.

I've created a Case statement with 8 different possible configuration from my system and the Case statement will at least be called 20 times with 20 unique ID's. f.eks. = 112 AS keyword1, = 113 AS keyword2, etc.

So now I've done some research and I've made some nice progress but now my question is:
Whats the best way to optimize my query?

```
-- Quick overview of all case conditions
-- 1. 'A,R,RO,H'
-- 2. 'A,R,H'
-- 3. 'A,R,RO'
-- 4. 'A,R'
-- 5. 'A,RO,H
-- 6. 'A,RO'
-- 7. 'A,H'
-- 8. 'A'

SELECT dtg.itemtypegroupname AS 'DTG', dt.itemtypename AS 'DT',
(SELECT (CASE
-- 1)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,R,RO,H'
-- 2)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,R,H'
-- 3)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,R,RO'
-- 4)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,R'
-- 5)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,RO,H'
-- 6)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,RO'
-- 7)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,H'
-- 8)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A'
 END) 
 FROM [x].[itemtypexkeyword] itxk WHERE itxk.itemtypenum = dt.itemtypenum AND 
itxk.keytypenum = 112) AS Keyword1
FROM [x].[doctype] dt
INNER JOIN x.itemtypegroup dtg ON dt.itemtypegroupnum = dtg.itemtypegroupnum
```

Within each CASE statement I'm going to have a FROM WHERE = 112 ETC.
Is there a way to minimize the amount of lines maybe to put the case into a variable or what's possible?

Below is what I dont want to do because of optimization.

```
SELECT dtg.itemtypegroupname AS 'DTG', dt.itemtypename AS 'DT',
(SELECT (CASE
-- 1)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,R,RO,H'
-- 2)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,R,H'
-- 3)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,R,RO'
-- 4)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,R'
-- 5)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,RO,H'
-- 6)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,RO'
-- 7)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,H'
-- 8)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A'
 END) 
 FROM [x].[itemtypexkeyword] itxk WHERE itxk.itemtypenum = dt.itemtypenum AND 
itxk.keytypenum = 112) AS keyword1,
(SELECT (CASE
-- 1)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,R,RO,H'
-- 2)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,R,H'
-- 3)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,R,RO'
-- 4)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,R'
-- 5)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,RO,H'
-- 6)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 1 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A,RO'
-- 7)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 1 THEN 'A,H'
-- 8)
WHEN itxk.keyreq = 0 AND itxk.readonly = 0 AND itxk.hidden = 0 THEN 'A'
 END) 
 FROM [x].[itemtypexkeyword] itxk WHERE itxk.itemtypenum = dt.itemtypenum AND 
itxk.keytypenum = 113) AS keyword2
FROM [x].[doctype] dt
INNER JOIN hsi.itemtypegroup dtg ON dt.itemtypegroupnum = dtg.itemtypegroupnum
```

My Out put looks great I just need some advice so i can cut some SQL lines away if you know what i mean :)

[image: Result if fine :)]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT dtg.itemtypegroupname AS 'DTG', dt.itemtypename AS 'DT',
( SELECT 'A' + CASE WHEN itxk.keyreq = 1 THEN ', R' ELSE '' END 
             + CASE WHEN itxk.readonly = 1 THEN ', RO' ELSE '' END          
             + CASE WHEN itxk.hidden = 1 THEN ', H' ELSE '' END
FROM    [x].[itemtypexkeyword] itxk 
WHERE   itxk.itemtypenum = dt.itemtypenum 
AND     itxk.keytypenum = 112 
) AS Keyword1
FROM [x].[doctype] dt
INNER JOIN x.itemtypegroup dtg ON dt.itemtypegroupnum = dtg.itemtypegroupnum
```

Or with `IIF()`:

```
SELECT dtg.itemtypegroupname AS 'DTG', dt.itemtypename AS 'DT',
( SELECT 'A' + IIF( itxk.keyreq = 1, ', R', '') 
             + IIF( itxk.readonly = 1, ', RO', '')          
             + IIF( itxk.hidden = 1, ', H', '')
FROM    [x].[itemtypexkeyword] itxk 
WHERE   itxk.itemtypenum = dt.itemtypenum 
AND     itxk.keytypenum = 112 
) AS Keyword1
FROM [x].[doctype] dt
INNER JOIN x.itemtypegroup dtg ON dt.itemtypegroupnum = dtg.itemtypegroupnum
```

Above solutions will increase readability but not performance.